# Remove "computer" and "network" categories from Nautilus sidebar (ubuntu 12.04 running Cinnamon 1.4)

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, cinnamon, places

I am wondering if it is possibly to completely remove the "computer" and "network" categories from Nautilus sidebar. I would like to do this because the locations that fall under them cannot be edited and I don't use those. Instead, I prefer to specify my own locations which I can do through the Bookmarks. This is all fine, but the "computer" and "network" just sit there doing nothing (potentially distracting).

It seems these categories are hardcoded in Nautilus 3.4.2? At least I can't find a way to remove them. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: you can remove/edit the entries under `Computer` from the `Bookmarks` entry of Nautilus, is it what you want?

Comment: Basically I want to have control over the entries I see in the sidebar. I can edit the entries under 'Bookmarks', but the ones under 'Computer' and 'Network' are fixed in Nautilus 3.4.2. So, if it would be possible to remove 'Computer' and 'Network' altogether, only 'Bookmarks' would remain for which I can control which entries are shown

Comment: Indeed they are hardcoded, you'll have to edit the source code and then install your version.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not even an issue for you anymore after all this time but I was having a very similar problem and this was one of the first few posts to come up on Google so hopefully this can help others.

In Nautilus click view > Show Hidden Files then from your home directory go to /.config/ in there you will find a file called user-dirs.dirs this contains the entries under 'Computer'.

**MAKE SURE TO BACK UP ANYTHING YOU CHANGE**

If you change, for example, `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads` to just `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"` the downloads folder will no longer show up under 'Computer' in the sidebar.

You can also just comment out every line, in which case it will only show 'Home', 'File System' and 'Trash'. It will keep those other directories as bookmarks though so you can do what you like with them.

This will not remove the 'Computer' entry entirely, just remove its entries, but it will make it look considerably cleaner. Sorry I can't help on the 'Network' Entry.

Sources: Personal experience trying to restore missing entries under 'Computer'.

Answer (score 0):

[Run the command as root user:](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+question/186540)

`chmod 744 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse`

PS: although it's about access, not about distraction...