# Remove Network and Connect to server from sidebar

Tags: 16.04, filemanager

In Ubuntu 16.04, Can I remove the two items `Network` and `Connect to server` from the sidebar in file manager? I don't need them at all and want to add some useful bookmarks there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove bookmarks from the Nautilus sidebar?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-the-nautilus-sidebar)

Comment: Nope, it is not a duplicate to what you mentioned. That question and some other similar posts are addressing a different thing though related to the same panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the fact that the *network* and *connect to server* entries in *nautilus  sidebar* are **[hardcoded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152505/remove-computer-and-network-categories-from-nautilus-sidebar-ubuntu-12-04-r)** and can only changed by *editing the sources code* of nautilus.

Now if your willing to go down that route this should be helpful:

- [How can I edit Nautilus Places sidebar and Unity QuickList?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325518/how-can-i-edit-nautilus-places-sidebar-and-unity-quicklist)

That link shows how to go about doing this. Another option I saw was using *nemo file manager*

- https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo